# Where does the COPY command in docker copy from?

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I have this dockerfile ,

```
# Start from the alpine image that is smaller but no fancy tools
FROM alpine:3.13

# Use /usr/src/app as our workdir. The following instructions will be executed in this location.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy the hello.sh file from this location to /usr/src/app/ creating /usr/src/app/hello.sh
COPY hello.sh .

# Alternatively, if we skipped chmod earlier, we can add execution permissions during the build.
# RUN chmod +x hello.sh

# When running docker run the command will be ./hello.sh
CMD ./hello.sh
```

on the COPY command i'm copying the file called hello.sh , where I have the file within my local directory same folder as the dockerfile , is it copying it from my local machine to the container or how exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

It copies from the *build context*, the directory argument to `docker build`.

```bash
docker build .
#            ^  this directory
```

You occasionally see setups where the Dockerfile isn't in the root of the repository, and in this case `COPY` is still relative to the build-context directory, not the Dockerfile location.

```bash
docker build -f deploy/docker/Dockerfile .
#                                        ^  still this directory
```

If the left-hand side of `COPY` looks like an absolute path, or if it begins with a `..`, first it is normalized to remove all leading `..` and then it is interpreted relative to the build context.

```bash
# All four of these copy the same file, in the build-context directory itself
COPY hello.sh ./
COPY ./hello.sh ./
COPY /hello.sh ./
COPY ../hello.sh ./
```

If you are in a remote-Docker setup (including cases where you set `$DOCKER_HOST` to an ssh connection, or where your Docker is in a VM) the files begin on the local system where you run `docker build`, and the context is sent as part of the build request.  Anything that is present in a `.dockerignore` file is not available to be copied.